# Find and Replace in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: find-and-replace, libreoffice-calc

So I have a Price column and all the values has a `£` prefixed. These are formatted string. I tried via the Find & Replace function to replace all of these with nothing, but I can't seem to get it to work.

- Search For is set to `£`
- Replace with is set to `EMPTY`

`Search Formatted display string` is checked

Clicking Replace all, just returns search results and nothing else.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Is it a bug or do I need to write a function to replace the character?

Comment: How is the Price column formatted? As a currency? Change the format to a suitable number format.

Comment: @DavidPostill  not sure - a noob when it comes to these sortsa things:) how does one check?

Comment: @DavidPostill I think you were right, found a format cells option -> changed to number -1234.00 and got desired output :) should I add answer or not worth it>?

Comment: Feel free to add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @DavidPostill - I didn't even consider the fact the column was formatted as currency (despite using `search formatted display string` option).

I selected the column and used the `Format Cells..` option to set to `Number(-1234.00)` to get my desired output